# Using fread and fwrite

Tags: c, fwrite

I am trying to learn how to use fread and fwrite.
Here I am trying to print the contents of a file on standard output.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{
FILE *fp; 
fp = fopen("largest.c", "r+");
int c = fwrite(fp, sizeof(fp), 1, stdout);

printf("Output is 1 if write succesful! : %d\n", c);

return 0;
}
```

This doesn't work. Shows some garble on the screen. why?

Comment: it should be `c  = fwrite(fp, sizeof(int), 1, stdout);`  , 1 if you wants to write one int. You wants read or write **?**

Comment: Check out http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/ for read example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you are never *reading* from the file you opened.

Instead, you are dumping the in-memory definition of the `FILE` data structure (something which is internal to the standard library implementation) to `stdout`, producing garbled output.

You must have a buffer of bytes, into which you first read from `fp`, then write the newly-read data to `stdout`:

```
FILE *fp;
char buffer[4096];

/* ... */
const size_t got = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof buffer, fp);
fwrite(buffer, 1, got, stdout);
```

The above adds a `buffer` of characters, and does a single `fread()` call to attempt to fill that buffer with data from the `fp` file (I didn't repeat the `fopen()` call, that should still happen of course).

It then calls `fwrite()`, handing it the buffer containing data read from the file.

Note that this will read (and thus write) at most up to 4096 characters; if the input file is larger you won't see the remaining data. This can be fixed by doing the above in a loop, stopping when `fread()` returns 0.

By the way, your usage reminds me of the Linux-specific [`sendfile()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendfile) function, where you really do get to skip doing the reading at the application level. Instead that's done inside the kernel, which presumably opens it up for optimizations. This is probably a bit above your current level, though.

Comment: Is the size of *fp equal to `got` or not?

Comment: @earik87 Absolutely not, `sizeof *fp` is just the size of the standard library's `FILE` structure implementation and tells you nothing about the state of the I/O being done.